# Time series, lubridate, and the seq function

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm just starting my adventure with the lubridate package and the dates in R. And at the beginning I was surprised by some behavior. Because when I do this `seq(ymd("2021-01-01"), ymd("2021-01-04"), ddays(1))` I only get one date `[1]" 2021-01-01"`. But when I do this `seq(ymd_h("2021-01-01 00"), ymd_h("2021-01-04 00"), ddays(1))` I get the more expected result which is four dates `"2021- 01-01 UTC" "2021-01-02 UTC" "2021-01-03 UTC" "2021-01-04 UTC"`.
I admit that it surprised me a lot.
I will be very grateful for explaining in simple words why this is happening.

And immediately the second question. Is there any function like `seq` that would correctly understand the `d...` functions in the lubridate package (ddays, dhours, dminutes etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seq is not part of the lubridate package and doesn't understand the `d...` functions.
ymd returns a Date, so when you call seq, you are using seq.Date.
You want `seq(ymd("2021-01-01"), ymd("2021-01-04"), "days")`

ymd_h returns a POSIXct object, so then seq is using seq.POSIXct.
You again want `seq(ymd_h("2021-01-01"), ymd_h("2021-01-04"), "days")`, but now the result is a POSIXct vector.

See the help for seq.Date and seq.POSIXct to see how they differ.

The new `clock` package has many good functions for date manipulation, including one called `date_seq` you might find useful.